# How to Initialize an Object and access its values from different methods - Kotlin

Tags: android, object, kotlin, android-activity

I am kind of new to Android. I can't figure this out. I want to create an object that is accessible from two different functions. Here is the object:

```
class Person(var firstName: String="", var lastName: String="", var order: List<Orders> )
class Order(var orderId: String="", var orderTitle: String="")
```

Then in an activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     
     var order: Order()
     var person: Person(order) //I am sure I am not doing this right
}

fun Function1(){
    person.order[1].orderTitle = "New Order" //to update order title
}

fun Function2(){
   // to read new order title  
    var newOrderTitle = person.order[1].orderTitle
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

You created your Person instance as a local variable inside the `onCreate()` function, so it is only accessible inside the `onCreate()` function. To make it accessible from your other functions, it needs to be a property member of the class (defined outside any functions). You also need to use the `=` symbol to set the initial value. The `:` symbol is for declaring what type the property or variable is, and is optional in most cases.

By the way, in Kotlin, the convention is to always start function names with a lower-case letter, so it is easy to distinguish them from constructors. (This differs from languages like C#, where the `new` keyword makes constructor calls obvious.)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    var order = Order()
    var person = Person(order)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun function1(){
        person.order[1].orderTitle = "New Order" //to update order title
    }

    fun function2(){
       // to read new order title  
        var newOrderTitle = person.order[1].orderTitle
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as what @TenFour04 says about making the variables visible to the functions, there's a couple of problems with how you're creating your `Person` object.

First, you're using default values for everything so you don't need to pass in a value for every parameter, right? That's how you can call `Order()` without providing any other data. But if you *are* passing in data, like with your `Person(order)` call, you need to tell it which parameter you're passing by using a named argument:

`Person(order = order)`

using the same name for the variable you're passing in and the name of the argument maybe makes it look more confusing, but you're specifically saying "the argument called `order`, here's a value for it".

You can pass in arguments without names, but you have to provide them in the order they're declared - so the 1st argument (a `String`), or the 1st **and** 2nd, or the 1st, 2nd **and** 3rd. Since you want to jump straight to the 3rd argument, you need to explicitly name it.

---

Second issue is your 3rd argument's type isn't `Order`, it's a `List` of orders. You can't just pass in one - so you need to wrap it in a list:

`Person(order = listOf(order))`

that's all you need to do!

---

The third problem is you've actually written the type as `List<Order`**`s`**`>` (sorry about the formatting). The type is `Order`, so we say `List<Order>` because it's a list holding objects of the `Order` type. You can use plurals in your variable names though (like `val listOfOrders: List<Order>`)